# What's the purpose of `tns livesync` apart from the `--watch` flag?

Tags: android, genymotion, nativescript

When I run `tns livesync android --watch`, it detects when I save a file in my project and refreshes my GenyMotion emulator.

When I run `tns livesync android`, it detects when I save a file, outputting "Applying changes...\nSuccessfully synced application org.app.user on device 192.168.56.101:5555" but doesn't refresh the emulator.

What's the point of running `livesync` without the `--watch` flag?

Comment: `livesync` doesn't do a complete rebuild. This is faster but can trip you up in certain cases.

Comment: Don't you want to post this as the answer with maybe a couple of those cases?

Comment: @Wainage thanks for helping us understand the difference between livesync and run. The question still remains: what is the difference between livesync with --watch and livesync without --watch?